# Try to create an entity within Azure functions fails with "Method not found"

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, azure-functions

Hi I try to create an entity (in CRM 365) within an Azure function.
I use the following code for doing that:

```
     using (CrmServiceClient crmSvc = new CrmServiceClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MSD_Q"].ConnectionString))
     {
         if(crmSvc.IsReady)
         {   

             Entity account = new Entity("account");
             account["name"] = inputJson.contactdetails.company.ToString();
             Guid response = crmSvc.Create(account);
         }
     }
```

but when I execute the create method I get the following error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.crmFunction. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. f-crmCreateTicket__1492291149: Method not found: 'System.Guid Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient.Create(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity)'.
```

The project.json in azure function looks like the following:

```
{
 "frameworks": {
   "net46": {
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies": "8.2.0",
       "Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly": "8.2.0",
       "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.1.0"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I try to figure out what I do wrong. Because an hour ago with the same code, it worked very well. But I dodn't change s.th. in Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Can you add some exception handling to see if there is any more detail to the exception? Also, does the code work locally with the azure functions cli or other app?

Comment: Do you happen to have any CRM SDK assemblies in your function's bin folder or deployed to your function app?

Comment: Also, could you also log the output of `typeof(StringBuilder).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()` and `typeof(StringBuilder).Assembly.Location`

Comment: Hi I used the wrong assemblies, but I didn't get any warnings or compilation error. But with the assemblies referenced below it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I fixed the issue by using the following references. 
After that it worked for now.

```
{
"frameworks": {
"net46": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies": "8.2.0.2",
    "Microsoft.CrmSdk.Deployment": "8.2.0.2",
    "Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions": "7.1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly": "8.1.0",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

}
}

I think that there will be missing the additional assemlbies.